# Excel VBA Sub breaking after .UsedRange.Delete

Tags: excel, vba, crash, exit, break

I have an excel project where I have tables in sheets (a basic database). The aim is to track the progress of pupils regarding different objectives they have to fulfill in different matters (and sub, sub-sub and sub-sub-sub-matters). I am trying to make a UserForm for the teacher to select a specific pupil, matter, sub...sub-mater set and get the level achieved in the objectives corrsponding to that specific set. I am at the stage of selecting a set of parameters :

[UserForm, not finished](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpwZT.png)

My problem is : in the case I select a matter, then a sub-matter, and then come back to change the main matter, Excel is doing something super weird. It stops a Sub after a specific line and .Activate does not work anymore for selecting a sheet in other Subs:

```
Sub ListMatieres_Change()
    If Not IsNull(ListMatieres.Column(0)) Then
        With Worksheets("S-matiere_tmp")
            .Activate
            .UsedRange.Delete 'Stops after this line------------------------------------------------
            getRows("S-matiere", "s_matiere", "Parent", ListMatieres.Column(0)).Copy
            .Activate
            Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            ListSmatieres.RowSource = .UsedRange.Address
        End With
        Sheets("Accueil").Activate
    End If

    ListSsmatieres.RowSource = ""
    ListSssmatieres.RowSource = ""


End Sub

Sub ListSmatieres_Change()
    If Not IsNull(ListSmatieres.Column(0)) Then
        With Sheets("SS-matiere_tmp")
            .Activate
            .UsedRange.Delete 'Getting an error here, because the .activate has not worked----------
            getRows("SS-matiere", "ss_matiere", "Parent", ListSmatieres.Column(0)).Copy
            .Activate
            Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            ListSsmatieres.RowSource = .UsedRange.Address
        End With
        Sheets("Accueil").Activate
    End If

    ListSssmatieres.RowSource = ""
End Sub
```

Changing the matter triggers the first Sub, which triggers the second.

Here is a link for the .xlsm file : [Drive link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Bc8cj5_kJnnmUZ0oMjdfHwySn1TMtpWq/view?usp=sharing)

I am really clueless, because the error given by Excel is only a consequence of some unexpected behavior I cannot explain...
Any help is welcome !

Comment: Just a thought -- don't know if it is your issue or not -- but VBA names are case-insensitive.  Therefore, you've got ListObjects with the same name as worksheets.  Also, most of your `.Activate`s would seem to be unnecessary.  What happens when the macro stops?

Comment: You are not handling the case where your getRows function finds no matches.  No value is assigned to your Rng variable.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, thank you for the suggestions, but the names do not seem to be the issue, also because they are not exactly the same ("-" vs "_"). The .Activate everywhere are trials at fixing the issue, but some are not neccessary, I agree. The macro stops after the line described in comment, but that does not trigger any error message. The second Sub is triggered and the .Activate does not work, leading to an error on the second commented line (runtime error '1004', delete method of range class failed).

Comment: @tlemaster, you are right, but in practice in does not happen. I ran the code in debug mode and after the first commented line, the sub is aborted, getRows is not launched... But managing the empty rng in getRows is in my todo ;) thanks !

Comment: Ah, I missed the "-_" difference. Sorry about that.

Comment: When I try to duplicate what you write, I definitely do get error messages (and in other circumstances also).  Are you sure you have Error trapping set?  In your particular description, it is a 1004.   In another sequence, I get an error 91.